# How can i store the value of a React input element and use it in some other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am facing a problem with React input element, in which i want to take the input value (which is a number) and multiply it with another number and show the value on a span element.

I am open for any solution or changes in my code

I have tried to use normal javaScript but it is not working at all with React. such as getElementByClass("className").value

Here is my code

```
class Counter extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            totalPrice: "Total Price:"
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="counter">
                <input type="number" />
                <span> {this.state.totalPrice} </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is the internal state of the component. You are using it for a static label, which is not a best practice (quite useless if that label does not change inside the component, as it looks here). Take time to go through the official doc of react, it will teach you all these base techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by this:-

```
import React from 'react'

export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            totalPrice: 0
        }
    }
    handleChange(ev){
        let totalPrice = ev.target.value * 10 // your number here i have taken 10 for example
        this.setState({totalPrice:totalPrice})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                <span>Total Price: {this.state.totalPrice}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest you read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html and go through some React beginner tutorials as well.

Comment: you're welcome, but that was for Sam :) I was just complementing your answer.